# Using bootstrap with web.py's form

Tags: html, forms, web.py

I am using web.py in my backed to generate a form. I am also wanting to use bootstraps form class. This is a snippet from my html

```
  <form name="test" method="POST"> 
  $:form.render()
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="Login" />
  </form>
```

Which, when generated by web.py, turns into

```
<form name="login" method="POST" class = "register"> 
<table>
    <tr><th><label for="username">Username:</label></th><td><input type="text" id="username" name="username"/></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="password">Password:</label></th><td><input type="password" id="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="password_again">Repeat your password:</label></th><td><input type="password" id="password_again" name="password_again"/></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

However. This makes it difficult to add bootstrap features to my code.
One example directly from the bootstrap website is :

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Legend</legend>
    <label>Label name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
    <span class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</span>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Is it possible to add these sorts of features into my form?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$:form.render_css()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote class inherited from `Form` class with modified `render_css` method. It look like that:

```
class bootstrap_form(form.Form):
def render_bootstrap(self):
    from web import net
    out = []
    out.append(self.rendernote(self.note))
    for i in self.inputs:
        out.append('<div class="form-group">')
        if not i.is_hidden():
            out.append('<label for="%s">%s</label>' % (i.id, net.websafe(i.description)))
        out.append(i.pre)
        out.append(i.render())
        out.append(self.rendernote(i.note))
        out.append(i.post)
        out.append('</div>')
        out.append('\n')
    return ''.join(out)
```

I hope you'll find this useful.